# How can I access a python shared memory from cython?

Tags: python, cython, shared-memory, python-3.8

I have two processes, one that creates a shared memory and the second that accesses it. I'm using Python 3.8.

The second process has the option to access the shared memory using python functions only or via cython. The cython option fails - I get a SIGSEGV.

Is there some special way to get the shared memory within cython? The [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) don't seem to show how to actually get a python shared memory.

Process 1 (setup_shm.py):

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np
import argparse
from package.get_shm import main as get_shm
from multiprocessing import Process


def main(cython=None):
    arr_share = np.array([[1.3424, 23.24324], [1.4234, .08682]], dtype='f')
    shape, dtype = arr_share.shape, arr_share.dtype
    # Create a shared memory of size arr_share.nbytes
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr_share.nbytes)
    # Create array using the buffer of shm
    shm_np_array = np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    # Copy the data into the shared memory
    np.copyto(shm_np_array, arr_share)
    print('shared name {}'.format(shm.name))
    print('shared size {}'.format(arr_share.nbytes))
    print(arr_share)
    p = Process(target=get_shm, args=(shm.name,), kwargs={'cython': cython})
    p.start()
    p.join()
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()


def setup():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shared mem getter')
    parser.add_argument('--cython', action='store_true', help='Use cython to get shared mem')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(cython=args.cython)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

Process 2 (get_shm.py):

```
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
import argparse
import sys
from c_get_shm import Vectors

def main(name, cython=None):
    val = None
    if cython:
        print('getting vector using cython - {}'.format(name))
        vectors = Vectors(name)
        try:
            val = vectors.data.base[0]
        except Exception as e:
            raise (e)
    else:
        shm = SharedMemory(name=name)
        np_array = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2), dtype='f', buffer=shm.buf)
        print('getting vector using python - {}'.format(name))
        val = np_array[0]
        shm.close()
    print('val is {}'.format(val))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return


def setup():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shared mem getter')
    parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help='Shared memory name')
    parser.add_argument('--cython', action='store_true', help='Use cython to get shared mem')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(name=args.name, cython=args.cython)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

Cython class (c_get_shm.pyx)

```
#!python
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

cdef class Vectors:

    cdef public object shm_name
    cdef public float[:, :] data

    def __init__(self, shm_name):
        print('Vectors Class for getting shared memory - {}'.format(shm_name))
        self.__get_shared_array(shm_name)
        print('data is {}, {}'.format(self.data, self.data.shape))

    def __get_shared_array(self, shm_name: str):
        print('get_shared_array {}'.format(shm_name))
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
        print('shm buf is {} size {}'.format(shm.buf, shm.buf.nbytes))
        self.data = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2), dtype='f', buffer=shm.buf)
```

Setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("c_get_shm", ["./c_get_shm.pyx"],
              libraries=['rt'])
]
setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, gdb_debug=True)
)
```

I'm running the script with either

- python ./setup_shm.py --cython
- python ./setup_shm.py

The only way I've managed to see the SIGSEGV is with strace:

```
Vectors Class for getting shared memory - psm_23cd04df
get_shared_array psm_23cd04df
shm buf is <memory at 0x7f8b4d66df40> size 16
data is <MemoryView of 'ndarray' object>, [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV && WCOREDUMP(s)}], 0, NULL) = 868
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_DUMPED, si_pid=868, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f8b65698000, 16)              = 0
close(4)                                = 0
unlink("/dev/shm/psm_23cd04df")         = 0
```

I've tried gdb python and running the script from in there but there was no stack trace.

Comment: I'd think it should be `val = vectors.data[0,0]` (or at least `val = vectors.data.base[0,0]`). I doubt if that's your problem though.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is you never `close` it in Cython

Comment: These comments were actually very helpful as they lead to more errors being thrown instead of the code just seg faulting. I **think** I have a working solution. So closing the shared memory seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, it turns out out I didn't need to close in the cython class. The main issue was not declaring the shared memory as a c variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into similar issues, make sure to declare the shared memory in Cython. I'm assuming the SIGSEGV is because it is not allowed to access the memory unless you do this.

```
cdef class Vectors:

    cdef public object shm_name
    cdef public float[:, :] data
    # declare the shared memory in Cython!!
    cdef public object shm

    def __init__(self, shm_name):
        self.__get_shared_array(shm_name)

    def __get_shared_array(self, shm_name: str):
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
        self.data = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2), dtype='f', buffer=self.shm.buf)
```